# Access: Grouping in Reports

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a report in my Access database containing multiple fields, e.g., it looks like as follows:

*Name John 

Number 18

Place somewhere*

*Name John 

Number 19

Place somewhere*

*Name John 

Number 20

Place somewhere*

*Name Bogo 

Number 30

Place somewhere*

John can have multiple Numbers. As you can see, "John" is listed multiple times, each with a different Number. I would like to get just one detail row with the name "John", something like the following:

*Name John

Number 18; 19; 20

Place somewhere*

*Name Bogo 

Number 30

Place somewhere*

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to use VBA code in an Access Module to "string together" the repeated values ("Number" in your case). The general form of the code is:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public Function ListChildNames(ParentID As Long) As String
Dim cdb As DAO.Database, rst As DAO.Recordset, rtn As String
Const separator = "; "
Set cdb = CurrentDb
Set rst = cdb.OpenRecordset( _
        "SELECT [ChildName] FROM [ChildTable] " & _
        "WHERE ID=" & ParentID, _
    dbOpenSnapshot)
rtn = ""
Do While Not rst.EOF
    rtn = rtn & rst![ChildName] & separator
    rst.MoveNext
Loop
rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing
Set cdb = Nothing
If Len(rtn) > 0 Then
    rtn = Left(rtn, Len(rtn) - Len(separator))  '' trim trailing separator
End If
ListChildNames = rtn
End Function
```

(You will have to tweak the table and column names to match your table structures.)

Then, in the Record Source for your report, instead of using...

```
SELECT [Name], [Number] ... FROM ...
```

...you would use something like...

```
SELECT [Name], ListChildNames([Name]) AS Numbers ... FROM ...
```

...to retrieve the [Name] and the (concatenated list of) [Number] values in a single row.